# Prove $4a^2+b^2+1\ge2ab+2a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove $4a^2+b^2+1\ge2ab+2a+b$

$4a^2+b^2+1-2ab-2a-b\ge0$
$(2)^2(a)^2+(b)^2+1-2ab-2a-b\ge0$
Any help from here? I am not seeing how this can be factored

Comment: Complete the square in $a$ first and then in $b$.

Answer (score 5):

As a function of $a$, the minimum of the quadratic $4a^2+b^2+1-(2ab+2a+b)$ is $\frac34 (b - 1)^2 \ge 0$.

More precisely,
$$4a^2+b^2+1-(2ab+2a+b)=\left(2a-\frac{b+1}{2}\right)^2+\frac34 (b - 1)^2 \ge 0$$

Comment: To add some explanation: Consider the function $f(a)=4a^2+b^2+1−2ab−2a−b$. Since it is a polynomial of degree 2 with positive leading coefficient it has its minimum at the root of $f'(a)$, which is $a=\frac{1}{4}(b+1)$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x=(2a,b,1)$ and $y=(1,2a,b)$. Then by, Cauchy-Schwarz,

$2ab+2a+b= <x,y> \le ||x||*||y||=\sqrt{4a^2+b^2+1}*\sqrt{4a^2+b^2+1}=4a^2+b^2+1$

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by $2$, then we get:
$$8a^2+2b^2+2 \ge 4ab+4a+2b$$
and rearranging we get:
$$(4a^2-4ab+b^2)+(b^2-2b+1)+(4a^2-4a+1) \ge 0$$
and then
$$(2a-b)^2+(b-1)^2+(2a-1)^2 \ge 0$$

Answer (score 2):

High school solution: 
$$
4a^2+b^2+1-2ab-2a-b=\frac{(2a-1)^2+(2a-b)^2+(b-1)^2}{2}\ge 0.
$$